# Getting Following error in catalina log when trying to restart tomcat after deploying new software (BIRT Viewer)

Tags: java, tomcat, logging

> log4j:ERROR Could not create an Appender. Reported error follows.
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
>           at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
>           at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
>           at org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:198)
>           at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseAppender(DOMConfigurator.java:247)
>           at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByName(DOMConfigurator.java:176)
>           at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByReference(DOMConfigurator.java:191)
>           at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseChildrenOfLoggerElement(DOMConfigurator.java:523)
>           at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseRoot(DOMConfigurator.java:492)
>           at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parse(DOMConfigurator.java:1006)
>           at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:872)
>           at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:755)
>           at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.configure(DOMConfigurator.java:896)
>           at panaces.common.utils.logger.init(logger.java:424)
>           at panaces.common.utils.logger.(logger.java:223)
>           at panaces.server.GUI.ApplicationInitalizorServlet.init(ApplicationInitalizorServlet.java:39)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:963)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1600)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
>
> log4j:ERROR Could not create an Appender. Reported error follows.
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
>           at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
>           at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978918/log4j-not-finding-custom-appender-using-a-property-file) might help you.

Comment: At the same time i am getting following error in tomcat webpage when i am trying to start application from web page:Message:  
"FAIL - Application at context path /WebViewerExample could not be started".Can you please help me in resolving it....